# Using MoC in a Controller, instead of AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, model-view-controller

I have a simple program, click a button on the window triggers an IBAction in the AppDelegate and adds a new managedObject to the Context - no problems here, all works just as it should.

The problem I have is when I create a MainController to control the window - how do I do the same thing? One solution I've done is to instantiate an instance of AppDelegate in the MainController, link the button on the window to an IBAction in MainController which calls AppDelegate add method. This works, but not sure if this is the best approach.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass the `managedObjectContext` from the `AppDelegate` to your `MainController`.
In the AppDelegate method

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Declare the `IBAction(which adds the object)` in the `MainController.`

Link the `button on the window to this IBAction`.

This is what I do.

Comment: That sounds good, how do I pass the managedObjectContext without creating an instance of AppDelegate in the MainController?

Comment: Why are you creating an instance of AppDelegate in your MainController. Why not declare a managedObjectContext Property in your mainController and in - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification when you instantiate your maincontroller set the property managedObjectContext property with the App Delegate's managedOBjectContext Property which in turn would pass the reference of managedObjectContext to your maincontroller and you can keep all the logic of adding/removing objects over there.

Comment: I created an instance so I could access the MoC - that's the only way I could think to do it.

Comment: @littleDrummerBoy I edited my comment btw. I do this all the time this helps in keeping all the window logic in the maincontroller and not in the appdelegate which is a good approach.

Comment: I understand what you are stated, I am missing one piece to tie it together. In MainController, I have propery.... mainMoC declared. In AppController, in applicationDidFinish... what is the proper method to make it happen? Would MainController *mc = self.managedObjectContext work? (at work, so I can't try it yet)

Comment: No sorry it will not work because here you are instantiating an instance of MainController with an instance of MOC ??? Why are you doing that ! I hope this is a typo.... what you should do is mc.MainMOC=self.managedObjectContext. It would work given the mc instance of MainController is the same you instantiated to control the window in the first place.

Comment: Thanks - I will try tonight and report back. Appropriate your advice.

Comment: @littleDrummerBoy I edited my comment I actually didn't noticed your mistake of instantiating mainController instance with an instance of MOC which is wrong instead of instantiating the MainMOC property in the mainController with MOC.

Comment: I think it partially works - and yes, I was trying to abr. in the comment so I mixed things up. Here is what I have: MainController: property mainMOC; AppDelegate: applicationDidFinish.. MainController *mc = [[MainController alloc]init]; mc.mainMOC = self.managedObjectContext; It works mostly - builds with no errors. In IBAction have [self.mainMOC Save:&error]; Run with out throwing error. New problem, when trying to add to the context, I get an error -basically it does not see my model object?

Comment: @littleDrummerBoy Please post this question and with the error you are facing as a new question :) and if this answer solved your problem consider an upvote and accepting it .... !

Answer (score 0):

correction of your solution: you can pass appDelegate to any controller with simple code without do any properties etc:

```
#import "YOURAppDelegate.h"

YOURAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YOURAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate yourMethod];
```